# App Engine Version, Memcache

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am developing an App Engine App that uses memcache.  Since there is only a single memcache shared among all versions of your app I am potentially sending bad data from a new version to the production version memcache.  To prevent this, I think I may append the app version to the memcache key string to allow various versions of the app to keep their data separate.

I could do this manually, but I'd like to pull in the version from the app.yaml

How can I access the app version from within the python code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `os.environ` variable contains a key called `CURRENT_VERSION_ID` that you can use. It's value is composed of the `version` from app.yaml concatenated together with a period and what I suspect is the `api_version`. If I set `version` to 42 it gives me the value of `42.1`. You should have no problems extracting the version number alone, but it might not be such a bad idea to keep the `api_version` aswell.

**EDIT:**

@Nick Johnson has pointed out that the number to the right of the period is the minor version, a number which is incremented each time you deploy your code. On the development server this number is always 1.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to call os.environ.get('CURRENT_VERSION_ID','')

Comment: The second part of the version is the 'minor' version ID. On the development server it's always 1, but in production it changes with every deploy.